# php memcache not working with mvc

Tags: php, memcached

I have two different Controller. i am working with Zend Framework MVC

Controller 1. Set data

Controller 2. Get Data and display

So i did it simply:

Controller 1.

```
$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->connect('localhost', 11211) or die ("Could not connect");
$data = array('id'=>1,'Name'=>'Jonson');
$key = "PersonalDetail";
$memcache->set($key,$data,MEMCACHE_COMPRESSED,1200);
```

Controller 2.

```
$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->connect('localhost', 11211) or die ("Could not connect");
$key = "PersonalDetail";
$Data = $memcache->get($key);

var_dump($Data); //getting nothing.
```

I checked for the key if it is set or not.
and i get this it is set in Controller 1 . but when i run Controller 2 code and then check key.. i didn't exists there anymore.

Is this happening because i am connecting memcache again to get data? or is there anyother thing happening?

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Memcached keys cannot contain spaces, set the key to `personal_detail`. See the [specs](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/blob/master/doc/protocol.txt):

> Data stored by memcached is identified with the help of a key. A key
>   is a text string which should uniquely identify the data for clients
>   that are interested in storing and retrieving it.  Currently the
>   length limit of a key is set at 250 characters (of course, normally
>   clients wouldn't need to use such long keys); the key must not include
>   control characters or whitespace.

Comment: yes you are right.. but in Controller 1 after setting data.. i tried to get data with same key .. then it gives me data

Comment: @user3553297 Yes, that's probably because `Memcache` is truncating your `key` to make it valid. So I'm guessing if you used just `Personal` as the key in controller 2 it'd work fine. Just follow the specs and take my recommendation.

Comment: yes did this but same issue.. Can u tell me . in controller1 i have successfully set data, and i can also see the key. But after running conroller 2 the key is deleted or something happened with that... i cannot see that again.

Comment: @user3553297, that shouldn't make a difference. You have an error elsewhere.

Comment: what does mean of CLIENT_ERROR? This time ..it gives me this Key.. Why it is coming now?

Comment: @user3553297, it could be any number of things - a bug in memcached or something else.